# Accessing iframe with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing navigating the DOM with Javascript and running into an issue. I'm aware of cross site scripting is not allowed, but I have a question.

I can post the HTML code if need be, but for the moment had a simple question.

When I run

```
iframe_dom = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
console.log(iframe_dom)
```

This is what's printed out (abbreviated version)

```
<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;"> .... </iframe>
  #document
    <html>
      <head>..</head>
      <body>
        <iframe>...</iframe>
```

That's what I expected. However, when I try to navigate the tree by putting in:

```
iframe_dom.iframe
```

`undefined` is returned.

If I've passed the body of iframe into a a variable, why can't I navigate the tree?

Answer (score 0):

How is not entirely consistent across browsers, and if you're executing your script on load, it may not be available yet.
Check out the Plunker below. I built it based on this: http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/

```
function getChildTitle() {
  var oIframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    var oDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument);
    if (oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
  console.log(oDoc.body.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML);

}
```

In short, from the iframe element, sometimes you want the contentDocument property, sometimes contentWindow property - depending on browser. Take whichever one exists (or isn't falsey, in the code). In some browsers you may need to use that object's document property.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cSRD0qh5kntYR6aS8f1H

Comment: `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.webpage.com" from accessing a frame with origin "chrome-extension://mbbpjgnlpelaafnnigciegfpelchjldl".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "chrome-extension". Protocols must match.`

Comment: That's the XSS protection. It will only generally be allowed if your iframe references something on the same domain as the parent.

Comment: Yea, is there a way to hack around this? :-D

Comment: Depending on the goal, you might get a certain amount of mileage out of injecting your script as a user script in a browser extension (though those tend to be sandboxed to a large degree so it depends on specific use case). Saving a local copy of the page or using an older browser might work if you just want to mess around with a copy of it. Otherwise, exploiting an XSS vulnerability - which you should only do if you are commissioned to do so by the owner of the site. Here's a starting point for that. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet